# UI of closed screen shows overlapping when 'popView Controller' is performed in UIKit code base project

Tags: swift, uikit

[image]

There are blue View Controllers and white View Controllers.

Press "button" on the blue screen to see a white View Controller.

The white View Controller has a large roulette. The roulette is made to show only half of the white screen.

And when you press a specific button on the white screen, it's "popView Controller."

The problem here is that at the moment of "Pop", half of the big roulette on the white screen is also visible on the blue screen.

1. I'm working on code base without Storyboard.
2. I'm practicing the coordinator pattern. (https://somevitalyz123.medium.com/coordinator-pattern-with-tab-bar-controller-33e08d39d7d)

I created a Navigation Controller and entered the screen through Push. However, there was a problem that the "UI" of the screen that closes at the moment of Pop overlapped.
(The UI on the closing screen was purposely made large)

I didn't have this problem when working with Storyboard, what options should I give?

Comment: You need to show your relevant code, including your class hierarchy and the code from both view controllers that builds your UI. You also need to explain the image that you posted in your question. We don't know your UI, and what parts are from the screen that's being popped, and what parts belong to the screen underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten that there was a top-level super view.

This was not a problem, but a natural result.

At the top view
Solved by applying "clips to bounds".

It's my fault for not looking into it properly.

```
self.view.clipsToBounds = true
```